# Haskell showing multiple result

Tags: design-patterns, haskell, matching

i need to take in an infinite list then when i do `take 40 counter list` will return a list of q1,q2,q3,q4 values in bracket or any form.

example of my code is

```
counter clock =
    let (q1,q2,w1,q3,w2,q4) = (flip clock clock, flip q1 q1, and_gate q1 q2, flip w1 w1, and_gate w1 q3, flip w2 w2) in (**q1,q2,q3,q4 - no sure about this part**)
```

how can i achieve this? Thanks

Comment: So `q1` to `q4` are infinite lists and you want to return a single infinite list of tuples representing all four signals?

Comment: Question is not clear about what it is trying to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`zip4`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3azip4):

```
counter clock =
    let q1 = flip clock clock
        q2 = flip q1 q1
        w1 = and_gate q1 q2
        q3 = flip w1 w1
        w2 = and_gate w1 q3
        q4 = flip w2 w2
    in zip4 q1 q2 q3 q4
```